# How to check airplane seat reservation in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to reserve a seat in airplane with an two dimensional array; everything work except it won't check if the seat is already taken.

```
for example: 
 1  A B C D
 2  A B C D
 3  A B C D
 4  A B C D
 5  A B C D
```

if the user choose row 1 letter A then it will be:

```
 1  X B C D
 2  A B C D
 3  A B C D
 4  A B C D
 5  A B C D
```

Then if the user choose row 1 letter A again it should display message says the seat is already taken.This is my code

```
void reserveSeat(char seatChart[ROW][COLUM]){

    int row;
    char colum;

    cout<<"Enter the row number with colum letter ex(0 A): ";
    cin>>row>>colum;
    colum = toupper(colum);

    for(int r = 0; r<ROW;r++){

        for(int c = 0; c<COLUM;c++){

            if(seatChart[row][c] == colum){

                //check if the seat is taken
                if( seatChart[row][c] == 'X'){

                    cout<<"seat is already taken\n\n";
                }else
                    seatChart[row][c] = 'X';   
            } 
        }//end of inner for loop
    }//end of outer for loop
}
```

Comment: What's with all the newlines? Please format your code so that it is easier to read.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer the code used to have comments and i deleted them and forgot to delete the new lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not have to run for loops for your solution, when you are taking rows and columns from user, You can simply subtract `A` from alphabet to check if this was the column, if you subtract `A` form any upper case letter It will become array counting like `A-A=0,B-A=1,C-A=2`
So here is solution you can use :

```
    int row;
    char colum;
    cout<<"Enter the row number with colum letter ex(0 A): ";
    cin>>row>>colum;
    colum = toupper(colum);
    int c= int(colum - 'A');
      //check if the seat is taken
      if( seatChart[row][c] == 'X'){
       cout<<"seat is already taken\n\n";
       }else
       seatChart[row][c] = 'X';
```

Comment: @user4581301 Edited!

Comment: Thanks  Mohammad Tayyab for  information you wrote down it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The second `if` can never be true because you are already checking if it's something else. You can probably get away with just removing the first `if` statement and just checking if it's an 'X' or not.

```
        if(seatChart[row][c] == colum){


            //check if the seat is taken
            if( seatChart[row][c] == 'X'){
```

Comment: "You can probably get away with just removing the first if statement and just checking if it's an 'X' or not." I doubt it, how can you reserve a seat if you don't know where it is?

Comment: I think that is given by its position in the array.

Comment: I mean according to the op s code, if you were to remove `if(seatChart[row][c] == colum)` all that would happen, is it would set all the values of the user selected row to `'X'` ( if they're not already 'X' ). The only information the code would have to try and reserve a seat would be the entire row, not just one seat.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Other answer shows how to remove the loops.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:  http://ideone.com/WfFsX9

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void reserveSeat(int x, int y, char **tab)
    {
        if(tab[x][y]=='X')
        cout<<"Already Reserved"<<endl;
        else
        tab[x][y]='X';  

    }



    int main() {

//setup
    char **tab = new char *[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = new char[4];
    }
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
            {
                tab[i][j] = 65 + j;
            }

//Lets try to reserve

    reserveSeat(0,0,tab);
    reserveSeat(0,0,tab);


//printing
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                cout<<i+1<<" ";
            for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
            {
                cout<<tab[i][j]<<" ";
            }
                cout<<endl;
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The answer deftly sidesteps OP's question by answering a different question. It also doesn't bother explaining what you are doing or why making it a code-only answer to a different question.

Comment: What the hell? It answers exatly that one. It shows how to implement the "seat is taken" issue.

Comment: dv ing: reasons: completely re-written the op's code, used a bunch of hard-coded numbers, used "magic numbers", changed the original functionality and introduced a memory leak for no apparent reason.